# How do I access the camera image so that I can send it via email?

Tags: ionic4

I am trying to take a picture (ionic 4) and send this image as an email attachment. So the intention is to take a picture, save it and send the saved image as an email attachment.

I tried following an example I got from this site: https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-image-upload-storage/

```
takePicture () {
    this.camera.getPicture(this.options).then((imageData) => {
        // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
        // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
            this.filePath.resolveNativePath(imageData)
            .then(filePath => {
                       // I am lost a this point.
                let correctPath = filePath.substr(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                let currentName = imageData.substring(imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, imageData.lastIndexOf('?'));
                this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
                this.sendMail(currentName);
            });
            //let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
    }, (err) => {
        // Handle error
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add [CameraOptions](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/). To save the image to your gallery

by doing this:

```
 const options: CameraOptions = {
 quality: 100,
 destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
 encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
 mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
 saveToPhotoAlbum: true
}
```

and use the image from your gallery to send the email

Comment: Thank you. That would solve it. Is there a corresponding key/value pair in the option for the CameraPreview plugin?